# wsgi.py no module named MySite

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to start my Django application on Apache on Windows server.
I have problem with the `wsgi.py` file.
I got the following error in server log:

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Target WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
   File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>\r
     import OctopusWeb\r
 ImportError: No module named 'OctopusWeb'\r
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Target WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
   File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>\r
     import OctopusWeb\r
 ImportError: No module named 'OctopusWeb'\r
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Target WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=1332): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
   File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>\r
     import OctopusWeb\r
 ImportError: No module named 'OctopusWeb'\r
```

The `OctopusWeb` is the name of folder in which the `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` files are.

My `wsgi.py`

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "OctopusWeb.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

All files I use are in `C:\Apache24\htdocs` directory.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

#### Edit:

I edited `wsgi.py` as @JoranBeasley wrote

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "OctopusWeb.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and now I'm getting the following error

```
   mod_wsgi (pid=1108): Target WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
   mod_wsgi (pid=1108): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py'.
   Traceback (most recent call last):\r
    File "C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>\r
      application = get_wsgi_application()\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application\r
      django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 22, in setup\r
      configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__\r
      self._setup(name)\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup\r
      self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\conf\\__init__.py", line 110, in __init__\r
      mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)\r
    File "c:\\python34\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module\r
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load\r
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
    ImportError: No module named 'OctopusWeb'\r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use:

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

as setting `PYTHONPATH` in the process is too late.

Use:

```
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

Also read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

which explains how to setup Python virtual environment and Python module search path.

Comment: Thank you @Graham. That was problem with paths. I hardcoded the paths and it worked `site.addsitedir('C:/virtualenvs/Lib/site-packages')` 
`sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs')` 
`sys.path.append('C:/Apache24/htdocs/OctopusWeb')`

Comment: As per the link, is better to configure it from the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add that directory to your system path or python path so python can find your modules

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),".."))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "OctopusWeb.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunatelly it did not solve the issue. I edited original post with new errors.

Comment: you probably need to add the parent directory as well

Comment: Still the same, unfortunatelly.

Comment: well its definately a path issue ... sorry i really cant be of more help than that

Comment: Thanks. I'll try with paths. Still it's helpful information